# Missing Operator or Semicolon error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi 7 if it matters.

```
procedure writeLog ( varName, varValue: string );
var
  length, i :Integer;
begin
  Append( logFile );
  ShowMessage (varName);
  For i := Length(varName) to 20 do       //line 37
  begin
     varName := varName + ' ';
  end;
  WriteLn( logFile, varName + ': ' + varValue );
  CloseFile( logFile );
end;
```

I get the error:

> [Error] felirat.dpr(37): Missing operator or semicolon

All the semicolons seem just fine to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declared a local variable named `length`. This local variable hides the function of the same name declared in the `System` unit (Delphi, as a Pascal derivative, is case-insensitive). So when you wrote:

```
For i := Length(varName) to 20 do
```

the compiler sees `Length` as the variable rather than the function. And that leads to your compiler error.

Possible solutions:

- Use a different name for the variable, e.g. `len`.
- Use the fully scoped name for the function: `System.Length()`.